# Exposure to asbestos, what to do with stuff and worries?

Tags: asbestos, renovation

I learned just recently about asbestos in condos I had few possible exposures:

1. In old condo put 20 screws and nails into asbestos wall and took them out later, without cleaning the dust. What to do with carpet, bed, clothes, shoes, camping stuff...where it all might got? Keep or throw out? Do I need to wash every single clothes?
2. In new condo around 3 tablespoons of dust/powder from possible asbestos drywall, popcorn ceiling, tiles  from old renovation was uncovered under new laminate floor and blew into whole aparment, carpet, furniture, blankets... What should I do with all the stuff? Keep or throw away? How to make sure the place is safe?
3. I am worried that also there is still some asbestos dust left from the old renovation in hidden places, between baseboard heaters, in dust in popcorn ceiling,walls, closets... since the previous owner said they didnt test for asbestos before renovation (renovation was done 2 years ago, condo is from 1970)
4. I am worried about constant exposure because of many renovations in the condo building in common areas, elevator, garbage chute...Also blowing it inside while the windows are open from renovation or if exterior of bulding is made of it and its windy...
5. I am worried about exposure in common areas of the building in laundry room, garage... as I doubt its being monitored and I seen falling paint, missing vinil tile, broken pipe insulation...

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: First, you should search this site and review the many, many other asbestos-related questions that have been asked and answered. Second, you should *relax* because most (maybe not all, but overwhelmingly most) asbestos related illness is related to chronic exposure over years and years, in an occupational exposure setting. Third, you should not make *assumptions* about whether materials are ACM and in a form that is hazardous (friable); you should get data.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it is 100% correct. Short version: asbestos != ebola virus.

Comment: If there is suspected asbestos in the building then you'll have to have it tested for. Nobody can tell just from looking or assuming that there's actually asbestos there. For professionally done work in common areas, abatement should be done - they'll seal off the area, double bag everything being taken out, hose off all the workers & tools each time they come out of the containment area, and have HEPA filtration that will remove it from the air. All these things may have been done _before_ you moved in.

Comment: [Some](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/217202/asbestos-exposure-need-help) [additional](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/214315/asbestos-concerns) [reading](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/211017/potential-asbestos-exposure-from-adding-screws-to-drywall).

Comment: In addition to the excellent comment by @JimmyFix-it I would say the *real* concern here is the ongoing renovations in common areas (item #4).  This is where you *might* get chronic exposure, assuming there is asbestos in these areas.  That is where I'd be concerned.

Comment: What material do you think had asbestos? There is so much panic and the chance that your wall board had asbestos is small in the first place. I bet you can tell we don’t see it as a problem. I have worked in construction full or part time for 50 years specifically specializing in remodels of old homes. I have gutted homes with known asbestos prior to it becoming a “scare”. I have stripped popcorn ceilings dozens without even a mask, I put up quite a few. I am not concerned but would I want my great grandson exposed no. It’s done worrying will cause more health problems than possible exposure

Comment: Thank you for all answers. My main questions are:
If I will have every day exposure of the asbestos forever becasue from those 2 exposures it still might be in furniture, clothes, shoes, hidden places? 
If I have constant exposure because of the renovations and possible detoriated asbestos in common areas and bringing it on clothes and shoes home?
If I should just not worry? Or should I constantly wipe things, wash things (I am really tired of it already as I have too many things, clothes, shoes, stuff)?  Or my only healthy choise is to throw everything out and sell the place?

Comment: I got into point, where I am scared of all dust I am wiping constatly, washing constantly, but I know I cant wash and clean every single clothes, shoes, furniture, and wipe every spot of the aparmtnent and dont know if washing (I have no drier, just front loading machine which uses very little water so not sure if it will wash anything out, or its even more contaminating other clothes as well), I am scared to go to even elevator or on balcony if i hear someone is drilling. I dont know if I should throw out carpet bc it was close when the dust went into air...dont know what to keep what throw

Comment: @FreeMan yes thank you, it partialy gave me some answers, thanks!

Comment: @EdBeal I think the wall in the kitchen what everyone is destroying here might contain it, and maybe when they removing everyting old from bahtroom? Not sure what in bathroom could be asbestos? The kitchen wall is like a drywall plaster deviding the kitchen from the living room and people want to have it open so they remove it and there the popcorn ceiling is demaged by it too. Not sure where else could be asbestos? Kitchen wall tiles?Some isolation? Electric plugs?Walls when they changing doors lining?

Comment: @tnknepp so I guess the only resolution here is to just sell the place and buy a newer one. It sucks that there are at least not notes about possible asbestos bc I am sure many ppl have no idea there is some and companies are not required to test it before renovation.

Comment: Mia, the only place I have found asbestos in bathrooms is when they had electric space heaters built into the walls. Similar for kitchens around or behind the stove / oven the homes that had asbestos usually had a smoke stack for a wood burning type stove or oven. As far as popcorn ceiling this is the texture that is very bumpy and soft if not painted over very sponge like, once painted the paint makes a hard shell but the material underneath is almost guaranteed to be asbestos. The bath and kitchen if it has it the sheets were usually fairly thin and very hard, nothing like Sheetrock /plaster

Comment: @EdBeal how about the wall dividing the kitchen with living room, will it contain asbestos in the joints? So when they tear it down it would release asbestos? There were tiles on that wall too. Tiles on bathroom wall too. And when they were changing doors linings, wouldnt be the wall also be disturbed? Our ceiling looks like sand is on it, but thicker sand so not sure what are the chaces of being asbestos? I am sure there must be asbestos in condo from year 1970, dont u think so? Mostly probably the joints?  Maybe under carpet too?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124023/discussion-on-question-by-mia-exposure-to-asbestos-what-to-do-with-stuff-and-wo).

Answer (score 7):

What's *actually true* is that workers in environments saturated with asbestos dust (i.e. asbestos factories and boiler construction), where they are huffing it into their lungs 8 hours a day, 250 days a year for 30 years... have a chance of developing a rare cancer. The fibers in their lungs and increase the chance of DNA replication errors taking hold (cancer).

Employees sued, and the manufacturers agreed with the government to create "Trust Funds" to pay out claims.  Each trust fund will pay only claims related to that company, which makes applying for relief *a little bit* complicated.  Just complicated enough to need to get a lawyer involved to build the case properly.

Contingency-fee lawyers charge 1/3 of the payout.

Getting the picture?

This has created a feeding frenzy of lawyers **trying to find** these victims so they can collect 1/3 payouts on these easy cases.  On Google search advertising, [mesothelioma has been the most valuable keyword](https://www.kantar.com/inspiration/advertising-media/most-expensive-keywords-on-google) in the industry for a decade. **They also carpet-bomb TV and radio** looking for these rare victims.

So *actually*, you are not comparing the *actual toxicity* of the various compounds in your home

- Asbestos
- Roundup
- Sucralose
- food oils over-heated in microwaves

*You are only comparing their level of (adverse) advertising exposure.*

Notice also how "novelty" figures into risk management.  Because this asbestos encounter is "new to you", honestly, you'd do all sorts of extreme cleaning if we told you to, because it's interesting. Contrast that to your feelings toward COVID-19 protocols... you're fed up with masks and social distancing and want to stop ASAP.  *Even though COVID-19 is infinitely more dangerous*.

The toxicity of asbestos in an occasional chance encounter like this, is nil.  All you need to do is not be moronic; i.e. don't grind it up and snort it.   Bonus points for using "wet" techniques for the clean-up.  End of the day, don't worry about it.

Comment: Right, even the EU (which is otherwise very keen on regulating the hell out of anything) has just a relatively low-key set of requirements for situations like getting rid of a whole lot of asbestos-cement boards or so, but that's it. The whole asbestos paranoia seems to be a US-only thing.

Comment: @TooTea yeah, basically because of the trust fund.

Comment: i.e, basically because of the lawyers...

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I understand that people who were not working with it have much lover chance of getting sick, but still there are ppl 13, 26, 30 year old getting it, many teachers dying from it, ppl who dont know about any exposure getting sick from it, what do you think about those?  So it feels like i want to do everything I can to avoid it if possible, but in these older buldings feels like its impossible. But if someone would tell me the exposure outside (from constructions) is the same as the possible small exposure inside from 20 holes, old renovation dust, ongoing renovations in

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica bulding, possible detoriation in common areas... I guess I would be calmer,but i feel like noone really knows too much about this. I just dont want to get higher exposure and higher chance of getting sick if I keep the clothes and furniture with possible asbestos, or stay living in this old bulding, but throwing everything out and moving to a new one would be very expensive and constant dust cleaning and washing things just makes my life very tiring and stresful.  I mostly dont know how much asbestos could be left in things, furniture, clothes from those 20 holes and

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica and 3 tbs of dust and from walking in common areas in this building.Or by walking on the street I would get the same amount of asbestos on my shoes and clothes anyway...

Comment: @Mia what you're saying is that the advertising that Harper has mentioned has done its job - it's got you terrified of something that has an exceedingly small chance of harming you. (Note the comparison to the most recent terror campaign being waged by the world's governments...) Whether you drive your own car, take public transport, or simply walk across the street on your way to work/shop/play, you've got a significantly higher chance of dying in an accident with a motor vehicle than you do of dying from asbestos exposure.

Comment: If, however, these words don't reassure you, then I recommend that you hire an asbestos abatement company to haul away every single item you own (without exception, even the clothes you're currently wearing), sell this condo, and move into a brand new house built in the last 6 months, somewhere in the middle of Montana to ensure you have the lowest possible future chance of asbestos exposure. i.e., you've asked for advice, the advice is "don't worry about it, your risk is very small". Now, it's up to you to take or leave the advice offered.

Comment: @MIa sorry for missing your comments earlier. With your case I'm much more concerned about **cognitive bias** -- you're attributing demonic power to this material, when other things cause cancer too - in fact, as asbestos sources are eliminated, those will increase (in percentage of causes). It seems clear you are relying too much on hearsay and web nonsense (particularly that written by scare-ya lawyers).  The hard science is readily attainable, you just have to be discerning about finding it (e.g. NIH.GOV) and be willing to accept data that contradicts your preconceived notions.

Comment: And the larger danger there isn't even wasted time, it's diverting attention away from *other* clear and present dangers that warrant attention *more* because their risk is greater.